# Join SQL tables in memory

Tags: python, mysql, sql, in-memory-database

I have 3 queries that each extract a table (see script below). I would like to join these tables in a new table without having to save tables from the 3 original queries in the database (only in memory). Is that possible?

I'd like to do this for two reasons:

1. I can't get `CREATE TABLE my_table SELECT ..` to work for saving tables on the server with `connection.commit()` etc.
2. It would be more efficient as these tables are rather big and I don't need them stored on the remote database (only locally, where I'm making a daily backup using the pickle files).

Code

```
from mysql.connector import connect as sql_connect
import cPickle as pickle

def extract_values_with_columns(cursor, query, multi=False, verbose=False):
    cursor.execute(query, multi=multi)
    results = list(cursor.fetchall())
    field_names = [i[0] for i in cursor.description]
    if verbose:
        print("Variables: {}".format(field_names), end=" ")
    results.insert(0, field_names)
    return results

def save(dset_name, results):
    with open("{}.pickle".format(dset_name), mode='w') as f:
        f.write(pickle.dumps(results))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    connection = sql_connect(user=SSH_USERNAME, password=DATABASE_PASSWORD,
                                 host='127.0.0.1', port=tunnel.local_bind_port,
                                 database=DATABASE_NAME)      

    print("Connection successful!")
    cursor = connection.cursor()                      # get the cursor
    cursor.execute("USE {}".format(DATABASE_NAME))    # select the database

    # combine ratings and tweet text
    query = "SELECT rt.tweet_id, rt.rating_id, rt.tweet_text, \
             {} \
             FROM contribute_ratedtweet rt \
             INNER JOIN contribute_rating ra ON rt.rating_id=ra.id".format(emotion_factors)
    results = extract_values_with_columns(cursor, query)
    save('agg_tweets_with_ratings', results)

    # combine profiles with demographics and technical data
    # joins should be done on the original variable name, not the renamed one
    demo_vars = "demo.gender, demo.age, demo.ethnicity, demo.education, demo.language, demo.done"
    tech_vars = "tech.entry_point, tech.ip_addr, tech.user_agent, tech.mobile, tech.referrer, tech.time_taken, tech.usage, tech.sharing_consent, tech.time_started"
    query =  "SELECT pro.username, pro.random_seed, \
             demo.id AS demographic_id, {}, \
             tech.id AS technical_data_id, {} \
             FROM contribute_profile pro \
             INNER JOIN contribute_demographic demo ON pro.demographic_id=demo.id \
             INNER JOIN contribute_technicaldata tech ON pro.technical_data_id=tech.id".format(demo_vars, tech_vars)
    results = extract_values_with_columns(cursor, query)
    save('agg_profiles_with_info', results)

    # add userID and tweet ID for convenience to rated tweets
    query = "SELECT pro_rt.profile_id, pro_rt.ratedtweet_id, pro.username, rt.tweet_id \
             FROM contribute_profile_rated_tweets pro_rt \
             INNER JOIN contribute_profile pro ON pro_rt.profile_id=pro.id \
             INNER JOIN contribute_ratedtweet rt ON pro_rt.ratedtweet_id=rt.id"
    results = extract_values_with_columns(cursor, query)
    save('agg_ratings_with_info', results)
```

Comment: Curious, why can't you perform #1? What is the error or is just too slow? And you explain your need but don't mention what is wrong with current code. Do you want to save queries as pickles or one large pickle?

Comment: There's no error. Simply nothing happens. The tables never appear on the database server and cannot be referenced.

Comment: I'm saving the queries as pickles using the code above. What I want to do is to create a new table by joining the results obtained from these 3 queries. However, I cannot do that since I only get the results locally and not in-memory on the server. I need to somehow keep the results of the queries on the server so that I can join them. Perhaps my question wasn't clear enough, sorry.

Comment: Since `CREATE TABLE as ...` is an action query you have to commit right after `cursor.execute` using database object: `connection.commit()` or set *auto commit* in connection handle. Otherwise actions are rolled back.

Answer (score 1):

Since all three queries relate with `qry2 --> qry3 --> qry1` relationship, consider using derived tables (nested queries in `FROM` or `JOIN` clauses). Below is a rough sketch where each of your queries are treated as their own table resultsets. However, this may return duplicates depending on nature of data. So dedupe within each subquery or in outer query.

Also, be sure to provide unique names to not repeat aliases in outer query select columns and importantly to properly use in `ON` clause between *t1*, *t2*, *t3* joins. So fill in `...` accordingly even renaming as needed with `AS`. And use `LEFT JOIN` over `INNER JOIN` if results are not expected to fully match.

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.*, t3.*
FROM
  (SELECT ...
    FROM contribute_profile pro 
    INNER JOIN contribute_demographic demo 
      ON pro.demographic_id=demo.id 
    INNER JOIN contribute_technicaldata tech 
      ON pro.technical_data_id=tech.id) t1

INNER JOIN
   (SELECT ...
    FROM contribute_profile_rated_tweets pro_rt
    INNER JOIN contribute_profile pro 
       ON pro_rt.profile_id=pro.id
    INNER JOIN contribute_ratedtweet rt 
       ON pro_rt.ratedtweet_id=rt.id) t2
ON t1.profile_id = t2.profile_id

INNER JOIN
    (SELECT ...
      FROM contribute_ratedtweet rt 
      INNER JOIN contribute_rating ra 
         ON rt.rating_id=ra.id) t3
ON t2.tweet_rating_id = t3.tweet_rating_id
```